# Javax Validation with RESTfull webservice(jersey)?

Tags: java, rest, bean-validation

I am currently working in a service where i have to use validation with service.We are getting the input from client through request class storing in the database using entity by repository,where we have to give the annotations and where we have to give the bindingresult parameters.While we calling the the service the validation have to take place.Here,I have attached the sample code.

**this is the service class where i tried to implement the validation**

```
public long create(@Valid Document document,BindingResult bindingResult,DocumentResourceRequest DocumentResourceRequest,
        long agreementId) throws Exception {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    logger.info("In DocumentServiceImpl createLoanDocument");

    Document documentObject = new Document(new lend(
            agreementId));

    documentObject.setDocumentType(DocumentResourceRequest
            .getDocumentType());
    documentObject.setDocumentDetails(DocumentResourceRequest
            .getDocumentDetails());
    documentObject.setRemarks(DocumentResourceRequest.getRemarks());
    documentObject.setDocumentStatus(DocumentResourceRequest
            .getDocumentStatus());
    documentObject.setCreatedBy(DocumentResourceRequest
            .getCreatedBy());
    documentObject.setCreatedOn(new Date());
    try {
        if(document != null)
        {
        document = loanDocumentRepo.saveAndFlush(documentObject);//DocumentRepository
        }else(bindingResult.getAllErrors())//if getting errors
        {

        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new Exception("Error in persisting Document-->" + e);
    }

    return document.getId();

}
```

'

Comment: I am not sure that this code will compile because you cannot use else and then condition straight away after it.

Comment: ya...if and else part wont work..can u give a suggestion..how to pass the parameters..(@valid class name,BindingResult bindingResult) how to work?

Comment: I am not exactly understand what is your problem and what you try to achieve. You want to make validation, but what kind of validation? What should you validate?